# Improving the efficiency of applying FindMinimum to a very large table

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I am working with a large table that has around 200,000 elements. Each element is a function of a single variable `u`. For example, one element looks like

```
(0.003 - 416.35 u)^2 + (0.0019 - 416.35 u)^2 + (0.005 + 416.35 u)^2 + 
  (0.0012 + 416.35 u)^2
```

I need to find the minimum of each element in `fun`. I have been using `FindMinimum` in the following way (where `fun` is a table of dimensions ~ 2000*100):

```
Minfun = 
  ParallelTable[FindMinimum[fun[[i, j]], {u, 0}], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];
```

This takes a few hours to do and I need to do this for multiple tables of functions.

Is there a significantly more efficient way to minimize many functions in the way I have described?

Comment: Are all functions sums of squares, and the coefficient of `u` the same?  If not, are there any other commonalities among the functions?

Comment: With the first expression in the question  designated `f`, `Solve[D[f, u] == 0, u]` is an order of magnitude faster than `FindMinimum[f, u]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's set up a (smaller) table with the functions in. I'm assuming they're all similar to the one you posted, but the results don't rely on that.

```
m = 50; n = 50;
fun = Table[
   Total[(#[[1]] - #[[2]] u)^2 & /@ 
     Transpose[{RandomReal[0.01, 4], 
       ConstantArray[RandomReal[500], 4]}]], {m}, {n}];
```

There are three obvious possibilities: `FindMinimum`, `FindArgMin` and `Solve` (where, in the latter, you find zeros of the derivative at which the second derivative is positive).

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 fminres = 
   Table[u /. Last@FindMinimum[fun[[i, j]], {u, 0}], {i, m}, {j, n}];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 fargminres = 
   Table[First@FindArgMin[fun[[i, j]], {u, 0}], {i, m}, {j, n}];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 solres = Table[
    u /. First@
      Solve[{D[fun[[i, j]], u] == 0, D[fun[[i, j]], u, u] > 0}, 
       u], {i, m}, {j, n}];]

(* {13.2571, Null} *)
(* {13.2213, Null} *)
(* {0.316872, Null} *)
```

Also check

```
fminres == fargminres == solres
(* True *)
```

So there's a pretty clear winner there. You may be able improve slightly on your parallelization by setting the `Method -> "CoarsestGrained"`

```
ParallelTable[
   u /. First@
     Solve[{D[fun[[i, j]], u] == 0, D[fun[[i, j]], u, u] > 0}, u], {i,
     m}, {j, n}]; // RepeatedTiming
ParallelTable[
   u /. First@
     Solve[{D[fun[[i, j]], u] == 0, D[fun[[i, j]], u, u] > 0}, u], {i,
     m}, {j, n}, Method -> "CoarsestGrained"]; // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.13, Null} *)
(* {0.12, Null} *)
```

Not a huge difference by any stretch. It may be more pronounced for larger matrices, or it may get washed out. Still, something you can try.

If there is a clear structure to all the functions in your matrix you may well be able to improve on this substantially. In the extreme, if you can find a general solution then all you have to do is plug in values and you'll be done much faster.

Comment: typo in D[fun[[1, 1]], u, u] ah nvm you already fixed it

Comment: @Alucard Yeah, had to re-run the timings, too. Just to be sure.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming[
 ParallelTable[
   Solve[D[fun[[i, j]] == 0, u ]], {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n} ];]  ` is slower than the third one but faster than the other 2

Comment: Finding zeros of the derivative would also find maxima. The functions in the array might only have a single minimum, but I didn't want to assume that. It would be a good example of using the form of the functions to get a speed up. Also, I wasn't using `ParallelTable` in the first round of tests.

Comment: i added the condition on the second derivative like you did and now, aside the parallelTable, the function is almost identical to the one you wrote. it  remains   slower though and i don't get why  since the workload is now distributed on 4 cores.

Comment: To be clear: Are you saying that, on your machine, the `ParallelTable` version is slower than the `Table` version of the same computation? It could be overheads if the cores aren't already active. Sometimes I have to run time trials a couple of times to get something sensible.

Comment: yes i used  this piece  `m = 40; n = 40;
fun = Table[
   Total[(#[[1]] - #[[2]] u)^2 & /@ 
     Transpose[{RandomReal[0.01, 4], 
       ConstantArray[RandomReal[500], 4]}]], {m}, {n}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 fminres = 
   Table[u /. Last@FindMinimum[fun[[i, j]], {u, 0}], {i, m}, {j, n}];]
AbsoluteTiming[
 weird = ParallelTable[
    u /. First@
      Solve[{D[fun[[i, j]], u] == 0, D[fun[[i, j]], u, u] > 0}, 
       u], {i, m}, {j, n} ];]  
AbsoluteTiming[
 solres = Table[
    u /. First@
      Solve[{D[fun[[i, j]], u] == 0, D[fun[[i, j]], u, u] > 0}, 
       u], {i, m}, {j, n}];]`

Comment: I get the `ParallelTable` version running slower the first time I evaluate the cell, but after that's it takes about 1/3 - 1/2 the time of the `Table` version.

Comment: @aardvark2020 -- Thank you all for your responses, especially aardvark2020. By considering all of the comments I was able to run everything in my code in under 2 minutes -- before it took over 4 hours!

Comment: @nsbd88 Awesome! Glad to hear it.